# How to remove the 'click' between frequencies?

Tags: python, math, audio

I wrote a script that generates frequencies and wrote them to a wave file. My problem is that there are 'clicking' sounds before and after each frequency.

I know that this clicking appears then be sine wave is broke. But how can I avoid this? I want to create an eurosignal generator like this:
https://wellen.uber.space/doku.php/user:vicuni:amateurfunk:software:eurosignal

The problem with the linked file was that it is over 10 years old and I could not make it run on my Python. I am using Python 3.8

Here is my Python script:

```
import structimport numpy as np
from scipy import signal as sg
import wave

# Parameters
sampleRate = 44100
frequency = 400
duration = 1


# define wave file
file = wave.open('test.wav', 'w')
file.setnchannels(1)
file.setsampwidth(2)
file.setframerate(sampleRate)



def generate(output, freq, dur):
    # create sine wave
    samples = dur*sampleRate
    x = np.arange(samples)
    sineWave = (32767.0*np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * x / sampleRate))

for i in sineWave:
    value = i
    data = struct.pack('<h', int(value))
    output.writeframesraw(data);


for x in range(1):
    generate(file, 1153.1, 1.0)
    generate(file, 1062.9, 0.1)
    generate(file, 1153.1, 1.0)
    generate(file, 1062.9, 0.1)
    generate(file, 1153.1, 1.0)
    generate(file, 1062.9, 0.1)

    generate(file, 510.7, 0.1)
    generate(file, 832.5, 0.1)
    generate(file, 652.0, 0.1)
    generate(file, 554.0, 0.1)
    generate(file, 470.8, 0.1)
    generate(file, 510.7, 0.1)
    generate(file, 0.0, 0.22)

    generate(file, 1153.1, 0.22)

    generate(file, 510.7, 0.1)
    generate(file, 832.5, 0.1)
    generate(file, 652.0, 0.1)
    generate(file, 554.0, 0.1)
    generate(file, 470.8, 0.1)
    generate(file, 510.7, 0.1)
    generate(file, 0.0, 0.22)

    generate(file, 1153.1, 0.22)

    generate(file, 510.7, 0.1)
    generate(file, 832.5, 0.1)
    generate(file, 652.0, 0.1)
    generate(file, 554.0, 0.1)
    generate(file, 470.8, 0.1)
    generate(file, 510.7, 0.1)
    generate(file, 0.0, 0.22)

    generate(file, 1153.1, 0.22)

    generate(file, 510.7, 0.1)
    generate(file, 832.5, 0.1)
    generate(file, 652.0, 0.1)
    generate(file, 554.0, 0.1)
    generate(file, 470.8, 0.1)
    generate(file, 510.7, 0.1)





file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The converted code of `eurosignal generator` for Python 3 is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# eurosig.py -- generates a random or predefined Eurosignal as WAV file
# Written Feb 2005 by Gerhard Grimm <gerhard dot grimm at gmx dot net>
# Donated to the Public Domain. Have fun!

import sys
from math import *
import struct
import random

class EurosignalEncoder:
    "Converts a sequence of 6-digit numbers to a Eurosignal PCM waveform"
    freq = [979.8, 903.1, 832.5, 767.4, 707.4, 652.0, 601.0, 554.0, 510.7, 470.8, 1062.9, 1153.1]
    duration = 0.1
    pause = [10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11]

    def __init__(self, Rate, Load, Limit, NumFile, WavFile):
        "Initialize internal encoder state and set parameters"
        self.rate = Rate        # samples per second
        self.load = Load        # 0.0 .. 1.0
        self.limit = Limit      # how many numbers to produce
        self.count = 0
        self.numfile = NumFile  # text file with numbers, read in player mode,
                                # written in random generator mode
        self.wavfile = WavFile  # WAV file (PCM), always written
        self.phase = 0.0
        self.lastnum = self.pause
        self.lastcount = 0

    def EncodeDigit(self, Digit):
        "Encode a single digit to PCM. 10 = repetition, 11 = pause."
        pcm = b''
        samples = int(self.duration * self.rate)
        omega = 2 * pi * self.freq[Digit]
        for n in range(samples):
            t = n / float(self.rate)
            sample = 32000 * sin(omega * t + self.phase)
            pcm += struct.pack('<h', int(sample))
        endphase = samples / float(self.rate) * omega + self.phase
        self.phase = fmod(endphase, 2 * pi)
        return pcm

    def DigitSequence(self, Number):
        "Encode a number to a digit sequence, looking for repetitions."
        if len(Number) < 6:
            if self.lastcount == 3:
                self.lastnum = self.pause
            self.lastcount += 1
            return self.lastnum
        digits = []
        for i in range(6):
            digit = int(Number[i])
            if (i > 0) and (digits[-1] == digit):
                digit = 10
            digits += [digit]
        digits += [11, 11]
        self.lastnum = digits
        self.lastcount = 1
        return digits

    def WAVHeader(self):
        "Provide the WAV header for the selected sample rate, 16 bit, mono."
        return struct.pack('<4sL4s4sLHHLLHH4sL', b'RIFF', 36, b'WAVE', b'fmt ',
                          16, 1, 1, self.rate, 2 * self.rate,
                          2, 16, b'data', 0)

    def NextNumber(self):
        "Get the next number from input file or random generator."
        if self.numfile.mode == 'r':
            # Player mode
            return self.numfile.readline()
        # Random generator mode
        self.count += 1
        if self.count > self.limit:
            return ''
        result = ''
        if random.random() < self.load:
            for i in range(6):
                result += chr(random.randint(48, 57))
        result += '\n'
        self.numfile.write(result)
        return result

    def DoGenerate(self):
        "Perform the actual encoding."
        self.wavfile.write(self.WAVHeader())
        number = self.NextNumber()
        while number:
            for digit in self.DigitSequence(number):
                self.wavfile.write(self.EncodeDigit(digit))
            number = self.NextNumber()
        # Adjust sizes in WAV header
        size = self.wavfile.tell()
        self.wavfile.seek(4)
        self.wavfile.write(struct.pack('<L', size - 8))
        self.wavfile.seek(40)
        self.wavfile.write(struct.pack('<L', size - 44))

def Usage():
    print('Usage: eurosig.py <numbers file> <wav file>')
    print('(to "play" an existing numbers file to a wav file)')
    print('or:    eurosig.py <numbers file> <wav file> <# numbers> [<load>]')
    print('(to generate a random sequence of numbers which will be logged')
    print('to a numbers file and "played" to a wav file -- load will be')
    print('assumed at 0.5 if not given)')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    limit = 0
    load = 0.5
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        # Player mode
        num = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    elif len(sys.argv) < 6:
        # Random generator mode
        num = open(sys.argv[1], 'w')
        limit = int(sys.argv[3])
        if len(sys.argv) == 5:
            load = float(sys.argv[4])
    else:
        # wrong number of parameters
        usage()
        sys.exit(1)
    wav = open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')
    es = EurosignalEncoder(4000, load, limit, num, wav)
    es.DoGenerate()
    num.close()
    wav.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to ensure that your sin wave ends at a point where sin(x)=0. So the expression `2 * np.pi * freq * x / sampleRate` must be a multiple of pi. This in turn means that `freq * samples / sampleRate` must be an integer so `freq * dur` must be an integer.

The easiest way to acheive this is first find the number of cycles and adjust the duration so you get a whole number of cycles

```
def generate(output, freq, dur):
    # create sine wave
    n_cycles = math.floor(freq*dur)  # number of cycle
    dur2 = n_cycles /freq            # adjusted duration
    samples = dur2*sampleRate
    x = np.arange(samples+1)         # want inclusive range
    sineWave = (32767.0*np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * x / sampleRate))
```

So for your first example

```
generate(file, 1153.1, 1.0)
```

The adjusted duration would be 0.999913277 s.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to generate continuous sine waves at changing frequencies is to increment the phase instead of the time, and compute the sin() or cos() from the new phase each sample, not from the time or sample index.

When the frequency changes, only the phase increment will change, which will likely only produce a small change in the next sample of the sinewave, for a new frequency, at a high enough sample rate.

This allow changing the frequency at any time, not just zero crossings, and still produce waveform continuity.

To prevent the sin() function from doing too much range reduction, one might wrap the incremented phase to stay between +-pi or +-2pi.